# Why Caste based political parties talking about secularism in India

Tags: parties, india

Many political parties in India are either caste based or religion based.
Some of them are

- Indian Union Muslim League
- BSP
- SP
- SNDP
- SDPI

etc. etc.

They work only for their caste/religion.

But why they are talking about Secularism in Election time?

Answer (score 11):

I am not very familiar with Indian politics, but one thing should be clarified from the beginning - the difference between secularism as understood in India vs. as understood in the Western countries. According to [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secularism_in_India#Comparison_with_Western_secularism):

> In the West, the word secular implies three things: freedom of
> religion, equal citizenship to each citizen regardless of his or her
> religion, and the separation of religion and state.
>
> In contrast, in India, the word secular does not imply separation of
> religion and state. It means equal treatment of all religions.
> [...]
>
> The term secularism in India also differs from the French concept for
> secularity, namely laïcité.[33] While the French concept demands
> absence of governmental institutions in religion, as well as absence
> of religion in governmental institutions and schools; the Indian
> concept, in contrast, provides financial support to religious schools
> and accepts religious law over governmental institutions.

So, in practice, there is no contradiction between being religion based and also support secularism.

Since you are talking about elections and parties goal is to obtain as many votes as possible, secularism can be used to attract voters of other religion, since they claim to equally treat all religions.